# Python AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python-3.x

I currently try to run a Python code such below:

```
def from_file(filename, sep='\n'):
    "Parse a file into a list of strings, separated by sep."
    return (filename).read().strip().split(sep)
```

I get and error like:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Filename is only the name of the file. You must open the file, to create a file object. And then you can read from this file object.

```
def from_file(filename, sep='\n'):
    """Parse a file into a list of strings, separated by sep"""
    with open(filename) as file:
        return file.read().strip().split(sep)
```

Comment: I have tried to apply your recommendation but nothing happens. Thank you very much for your reply